# Is there a way to change the name of an element in xml using xsl?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Trying to change UNICODE_STRING from my xml to ouput just "STRING" rather than Unicode in my table. I have created a table where I retrieve the "type" however would like to change the name and simplify it to just STRING.

Is there way to create a variable and change it to what I want?

My XSLT code is:

[

```
            <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Direction</th>
                <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
            
            <xsl:for-each select = "BATCH_EQUIPMENT_PHASE_CLASS/BATCH_PHASE_DEFINITION/BATCH_PHASE_PARAMETER">
            
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "NAME"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "TYPE"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "DIRECTION"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select = "ID"/></td>
                </tr>
            
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>][1]
```

and it works good. Just looking for a way to change the name of UNICODE_STRING from my XML.

Comment: XSLT - 
While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**: 
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its version.

Comment: What other values, other than `"UNICODE_STRING"` can the `TYPE` element contain? And which version of XSLT does your processor support? -- P.S. Your title says *"change the name of an element*" - but from the snippet of code you posted it's clear you are trying to change the [**string-value**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of the `TYPE` element, not its name.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to replace:

```
<xsl:value-of select="TYPE"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="TYPE='UNICODE_STRING'">STRING</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="TYPE"/>    
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, you could  shorten this to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (TYPE='UNICODE_STRING') then 'STRING' else TYPE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion Michael! I didn't really explain perfectly but i was able to find a solution to my problem. I used the following:

```
<script>function rep(){document.body.innerHTML =document.body.innerHTML.replace("UNICODE_STRING", "STRING");document.body.innerHTML =document.body.innerHTML.replace("ENUMERATION_VALUE", "NAMED SET");} </script>

<!-- this is where the script is called, notice its all done after the table is populated -->


<script>rep(); </script>
```

Using the replace function, I was able to change the output of my table.